# Check for Date Overlap and Generate Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, overlap

**REQUIREMENT**

Create a stored procedure to update data in a table [dbo].[TestData] post a successful data validation check.

The stored procedure will receive input parameters values for `@UniqueID, @LocationID, @Start, @End`.

***The above parameters will be used to update the data and MUST not create a DATE OVERLAP with other rows of data in the table.***

Brief outline of the steps:

1. Identify the dataset (using @LocationID, @Start, @End)
2. Perform a DATE OVERLAP check:
   Check to see that the @Start or @End values are not present in any other rows of the data table
3. Post Validation Result

   DATE OVERLAP = TRUE then generate error
   DATE OVERLAP = FALSE then Close of existing records and create a new single record

**STEP 1:Identify Dataset**

Check if data rows exist for the date range (Columns: Start, End) and LocationID, if it exists then move on to next step

Eg, Input parameter values to select the data

```
@[LocationID] = 'A002';
@[Start] = '2023-03-01 14:30:00.000'
@[End] = '2023-03-01 16:32 :00.000';

SELECT [UniqueID]
      ,[LocationID]
      ,[Start]
      ,[End]
      ,[IsCurrentRecord]
  FROM [dbo].[TestData]
  WHERE [LocationID] = 'A002'
  AND [Start] >= '2023-03-01 14:30:00.000'
  AND [End] <= '2023-03-01 16:30:00.000'
```

**Step 2:Date Overlap Check - This is the part I need help on please**

PERFORM A ***DATE OVERLAP CHECK***: Compare the '@Start' and '@End' date value from passed as an input from the stored procedure to the other records for the same LocationID.

****SCENARIO ONE:** GENERATE stored procedure error (DATE OVERLAP = TRUE)**

Input Parameters:

```
@LocationID = A002
@Start = 01/03/2023 14:30
@End = 01/03/2023 16:31
```

IF Date-Range-Check Column: @Start and @End is not present in any other rows in the data table

In this case there is an overlap with UNIQUE_ID = 1005.

```
01/03/2023 16:31 > 01/03/2023  16:30:03
```

**Generate stored procedure error.**

****SCENARIO TWO:** CLOSE OLD RECORD. GENERATE NEW RECORD (DATE OVERLAP = FALSE)**

```
@LocationID = A002
@Start = 01/03/2023 14:30
@End = 01/03/2023 16:20
```

In this case there is no overlap in the date

```
01/03/2023 16:25 < 01/03/2023  16:30:03
```

Then Close original records and create a new row as shown below:

[image]

Below is a script to update (Close records):

```
  UPDATE [dbo].[TestData]
  SET IsCurrentRecord = 0
  WHERE LocationID = 'A002'
    AND [Start] >= '2023-03-01 14:30:00.000'
    AND [End] <= '2023-03-01 16:25:00.000'
  GO
```

Below is an INSERT statement to create the New row:

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestData]
  ([UniqueID]
      ,[LocationID]
      ,[start]
      ,[End]
      ,[IsCurrentRecord])
  VALUES(
      1012 --MaxID + 1  generated
      ,'A002'
      ,'2023-03-01 14:30:00.000'
      ,'2023-03-01 16:25:00.000'
      , 1)
```

Script to create test data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestData](
    [UniqueID] [int] NULL,
    [LocationID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Start] [datetime] NULL,
    [End] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsCurrentRecord] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO;

INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([UniqueID], [LocationID], [Start], [End], [IsCurrentRecord])
VALUES
(1001, N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:10:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1002, N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:10:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1003, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T14:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T15:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1004, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T15:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T16:20:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1005, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T16:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T17:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1006, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T17:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T18:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1007, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-02T17:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-02T18:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1008, N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:35:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1009, N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T21:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T21:35:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1010, N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T22:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T23:35:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1011, N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-02T11:10:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(0, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T12:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T14:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1);
```

Comment: You don't appear to ask anything here; the above reads like a blog post and [so] isn't a blogging site.

Comment: The date overlap logic for the SQL is the part I need help with. 
I have tried to provide as much context as possible

Comment: But you've not explained what the problem is you're having solving the problem or what you're asking. Like I said, the above reads like a blog post, or a homework assignment; it's not a question as it doesn't *ask* anything.

Comment: You also shouldn't delete your existing question and then ask the same question again ... You should clarify your existing one.

Comment: Note your last row of sample data still has id=0 which I assume is incorrect?

Comment: Aside: The [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag information has a handy explanation of how to check for overlapping ranges.

Comment: @AarionSQL I do wish you would address my comment as to what is the purpose of the last row with id=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps of logic are:

1. Identify the rows that meet your criteria AND check the row following those rows using `LEAD`.
2. Store the results in a temp table since you need to perform 2 actions if the validation passes.
3. Validate the results and throw errors as required.
4. If validation passes, update the rows selected in step 1 and insert the new row as specified.

```
-- SETUP THE DATA
CREATE TABLE [TestData](
    [UniqueID] [int] not NULL identity(1,1),
    [LocationID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Start] [datetime] NULL,
    [End] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsCurrentRecord] [int] NULL
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestData] ON;
INSERT [TestData] ([UniqueID], [LocationID], [Start], [End], [IsCurrentRecord])
VALUES
(1001, N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:10:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1002, N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:10:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1003, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T14:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T15:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1004, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T15:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T16:20:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1005, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T16:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T17:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1006, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T17:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T18:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1007, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-02T17:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-02T18:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1008, N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:35:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1009, N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T21:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T21:35:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1010, N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T22:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T23:35:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
(1011, N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-02T11:10:00.000' AS DateTime), 1),
-- Whats with the following row???
(0, N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T12:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-03-01T14:30:00.000' AS DateTime), 1);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestData] OFF;

-- PROCEDURE LOGIC
-- Failure case
declare @LocationID varchar(50) = 'A002', @StartDateRange datetime = '2023-03-01 14:30:00.000', @EndDateRange datetime = '2023-03-01 16:31:00.000';
-- Success case
--declare @LocationID varchar(50) = 'A002', @StartDateRange datetime = '2023-03-01 14:30:00.000', @EndDateRange datetime = '2023-03-01 16:25:00.000';

with cte as (
  -- Don't filter by end date here because we need it for the lead window function
  -- Instead filter from the results of the CTE
  select *
    , lead([Start]) over (partition by LocationId order by [Start] asc) NextStartDate
  from TestData
  where LocationId = @LocationId
  and [Start] >= @StartDateRange
)
select UniqueId, LocationId
  , min([Start]) over () MinStartDate
  , @EndDateRange EndDateRange
  , max(NextStartDate) over () NextStartDate
into #temp
from cte
-- You normally make the end date non-inclusive
where [End] <= @EndDateRange;

-- I suspect you want to add another check here for if only a single row was selected, because if only a single row was selected there would be no need to update it?
if not exists (select 1 from #temp) begin
  throw 51000, 'No Rows Selected', 1;
end; else if exists (select 1 from #temp where coalesce(NextStartDate, EndDateRange) < EndDateRange) begin
  throw 51000, 'Date Overlap Error', 1;
end; else begin
  -- Update existing rows
  update t set
    IsCurrentRecord = 0
  from TestData t
  join #temp tm on tm.UniqueID = t.UniqueID;

  -- Insert new row
  -- Assuming UniqueID is an identity
  -- We can use top 1 because the values we need are identical in all records
  insert into TestData (LocationID, [Start], [End], [IsCurrentRecord])
  select top 1 LocationID, MinStartDate, EndDateRange, 1
  from #temp;
end;

select * from TestData;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t_2Eu62P)

Comment: I am testing it all out  and many thanks. Yes like your comment suggested I will have to process a sinnle row as well.

And also check that a @start is not out of range. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: All of your code with the logic provided works! So THANK You for that! 

Struggling to change the code to make it work for a single row

Comment: I was testing a scenario of a single row where the End < '@EndDateRange

declare @LocationID varchar(50) = 'A002', '@StartDateRange datetime = '2023-03-01 14:30:00.000', '@EndDateRange datetime = '2023-03-01 15:29:00.000';

I tried to add logic in the Block
if not exists (select 1 from [dbo].[Temp]) begin ... end

But it seems like I cannot reference the CTE for a second time. 

Do you have any suggestions for this please?

Comment: Hi Dale, I thought I had accepted it already with the arrow. Sorry I missed the tick and that is done,

Comment: I was going to post another question but was not sure if I should post it separately.

Comment: If you have another question, then  do post another question, certainly don't edit an existing question to add more questions (only to clarify the original question). However it should be fairly trivial to add a further check as another `if exists` statement.

Comment: I put another check in the IF EEXISTS block but referencing cte. It did not like me referencing cte again.

Comment: Yes as I said you have to reference the temp table. You can only reference a CTE once, which is why I assign the results to a temp table. Use the temp table for your error checks.